# How to use MultiThreading with MouseWheel Event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF application that is using UIElement control, this app contains 22 canvas and these canvas are hidden, on every mouseWheel 3 of these canvas will be visible, how can i make visibility/hidden of canvas by using 3 threads for each type of canvas (type 1 : 1 canvas for polygons, type 2 : 10 canvas for roads, type 3 : 11 canvas for nodes)?

Note : every zoom step (MouseWheel step), I should call ViewPolygonLayer(), ViewSegmentsLayers() and ViewNodesLayers()
How can I use 3 threads for each method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to manually create and manage all that by yourself?
You could write a behaviour attachable to those canvas in which you can subscribe methods to controllers' events.

```
class CanvasBehaviour : Behavior<Canvas>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            this.AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged += this.MyMethods;
        }

        private void MyMethods(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do what you want
        }
    }
```

You'll need to use `using System.Windows.Interactivity;`

Usage:

in your xaml, include

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and on the controller

```
<Canvas>
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <myBehaviours:CanvasBehaviour />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but I have to manage all that manually, 'cause I've a lot of canvas and every zoom step I've changed the canvas from visible to hidden and vice versa, I draw special World Map by myself and it contains huge number of segments and nodes so I've to separate all segments into 10 canvas and all nodes into 11 canvas.

Comment: I need to run 3 threads at the same time (Separate threads not main Thread),Can you help me?!

Comment: Then you need Threads or Tasks objects, depending on your needs. Assuming that you want all these 3 tasks done before the next wheel scroll, I'd suggest to change those method's signature to Task<bool> ad await them.